# AttributeError: module 'torch.utils' has no attribute 'make_grid'

Tags: pytorch

I tried following along with the PyTorch transfer learning tutorial and found it pulled an error code when I brought up the make grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's out of date. As of 1.11.0 it has been moved to torchvision.utils.make_grid instead of torch.utils.make_grid

https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.utils.make_grid.html?highlight=make_grid#torchvision.utils.make_grid